# Is there a Django or Python package which provides email anonymization?

Tags: python, django, email

I am working on an django application that does similar to what craigslist does when people choose to hide their email with the "anonymous" option when making posts. Is there a python package already does something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

A package would be overkill.  Why not just use a model with an anonymous flag?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField()

    def get_email(self):
        return "Anonymous" if self.anonymous else self.user.email
```